# Supabase update endpoint not working with authenticated users

Tags: supabase, supabase-database

I'm testing the Supabase RLS policies and when I try to update a store with an authenticated user I got a 404 error.

[image]

But when I try to use insert it works, but the rule of policies is the same!!

Answer (score 1):

Insert policy only works for a new row. You would probably need to create a separate update policy for your table.

This specific discussion might point you to the right direction:
https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/3476